# How to add a custom category property in Kylo?

Tags: kylo

I want to define some additional property  while creating 
a category in Kylo. For example, a flag kind of thing. If the flag is Y, pass that category to some database as metadata for that category. Is it possible? If yes, please suggest how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign custom properties to a category.

**1. Category creation with custom properties**

[image]

**2. View a category's properties**

[image]

These properties are searchable via **Global search**.

[image]

When the first feed runs in a new category, a `Hive` database is created with the category's name. You can check this in `Hive` via the command:

```
hive> show databases;
```

Comment: Thanks @Jagrut ,one more question ,can i access these properties which i have defined for the categories, via swagger UI ,or how to use these custom categories in code.

Comment: You can use Kylo's REST API. As an example, this will take the category system name and return details. (`http://hostname:8400/proxy/v1/feedmgr/categories/by-name/<category_system_name>`). The response has a property called `userProperties` that contains these custom properties.

Comment: can we connect with mail or some other platform I have a lot of questions if you have some spare time, thanks in advance.

Comment: `https://kylo.io` has useful information to learn more about Kylo. There are links to tutorial videos, documentation and community mailing list.